# Extending child properties in parent throws read only exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am making an npm package to validate elements, I need to achieve the following syntax to be actually useful and easy :

```
<validationLibrary type="numeric">
  <input type="text" placeholder"Sample 123">
</validationLibrary>
```

But my problem is with the child, the following throws an exception :

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children,function(child,i){
       child.props.onChange = function (event) {
         isNumeric(event.target.value);
       }
     })
```

My objective is for the library to force the child to execute the methods of my library it so the user doesnt have to do a millon configuration steps to get it working.

Any help?

**EDIT :**
Solution :

```
   let copies = React.Children.map(this.props.children,(child,i) =>{
       let copy = React.cloneElement(child,{onChange:function () {
         console.log("i overrode the default behaviour");
       }});
       return copy;
     })

    return <div>{copies}</div>;
```

Comment: Just to confirm your issue, can you post the exception that is being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since React v0.14, the `props` are frozen, it means you can't mutate them.

FMI: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#breaking-changes

So, what you can do is, for each child, return a **new** element. In your case, you will *clone* the element and add a new prop to handle `onChange`. You can achieve that using `React.cloneElement`:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement